# Linux bin folder is broken

Tags: linux

by mistake i accidentally broke my system , i installed 7zp with wine , i went to my media folder, my mouse struggled and i accidentally dragged a folder named with my user name into the main directory , i don´t know where the folder was supposed to be . the data inside that folder looked like the data from the ´´bin´´ folder. then i saw, that the bin folder was empty. i copied the data from the folder with my user name into the bin folder. I rebooted my system and received many error messages with ´´no permissions and fails´
After those messages it booted and i see a window called: Linux mint 20.1 Ulyssa (my user name)
(my user name) login : when i try to login, the messages is non stop popping up, i can only go in the grup terminal or what its called
,what should i do?

pictures :
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/721381687874813992/882713436084121640/WP_20210901_21_37_15_Pro_LI.jpg
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/721381687874813992/882713429503270982/WP_20210901_21_37_12_Pro_LI.jpg

Comment: Use a livecd, backup everything to external media you can disconect.  Then format and reinstall the system, and restore your data?

Answer (score 1):

As @Zoredache has recommended, I think you should backup and reinstall linux on your PC.

It is possible to boot in to a live cd and fix the problems which you would probably learn a lot from! But if you're not interested in doing it for the knowlege it simply isn't worth the time... And we don't even know what folders and files got moved, or where they got moved to...

If you however would like to fix it the manual way. The easiest way would probalby be to look into a fresh copy of your distro and go through all the files and folders there and compare it with what you have on your current PC. This way you might be able to see what has been moved and where it got moved to. So you then can reverse the action. It might go fast or it might go slow, depending on how much you know about what you might have moved etc.

But listing all the files (excluding my home folder) that i have on my workstation atm i got over `1 250 000` files. And you don't want to go over all of them by hand... So if you want/need to go through them all, you would probably have to write some script to compare all the folders and files on your pc with the ones on the fresh copy to see if you can find where the files went.

Comment: its all now repaired, but it dosen't boot in the user interace, but now i can go in my terminal and can re install the desktop,  can u help me? .-.
I use new in linux, i have use it in 26.2 in this year >->

I have found a backup of my system in a folder from 27.8.2021
and have copie all of them in my main directory